# Is it necessary to export and import stored procedures, triggers and indexes while dumping sql database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I use WordPress and I have always exported my database using the following command:

```
mysqldump -u user_name -p database_name > backup.sql
```

I never used --routines

Just wondering if I am doing something wrong, missing out on any advantages by not adding --routines while exporting my database.

P.S., I never had any server failure, hacking attempt or any misfortune needed to import those databases yet, but I want to make sure those database work when I need them to. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think a normal basic wordpress wouldn't include stored procedures or triggers.

You can check by adding `--routines` to the `mysqldump` and seeing if the output is different.

Adding `--routines` when there is none is quite harmless and probably a good thing to add just in case a plugin adds starts using those features.

`--single-transaction` would also be a good option to add to `mysqldump` if you are using innodb tables (and you should be).

Indexes are supported in your dump currently.

PS: checking a backup properly involved attempting a restore and checking the final result. Don't rely on static analysis of your scripts/procedures - test them.

Comment: Thank you for this @danblack. My database shows that I have a mix of tables on InnoDB as well as MyISAM. So if I use --single-transaction, won't it leave my MyISAM tables in an inconsistent state?

Also, I couldn't agree more on the testing point you made. I'll keep that in mind from my next backups.